# Zip folder to SVN?

Tags: c#, svn, zip

This may sound a silly question but I just wanted to clear something up. I've zipped a folder up and added it to my SVN repository. Is doing this all ok? or should I upload the unzipped folder instead?

I just need to be sure!

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with storing a zip file in source control.  Is the zip file part of the source?  Is there some reason it shouldn't be in source control?  What is it and why is it there?

Comment: I just thought I would Zip it together, Just wanted to make sure the person on the other end opening the file and extracting it, wouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Sure, you can commit a zip folder. That's a common file format, so why should anyone have problems with it? That said, you are not trying to use SVN as if it was simply a storage on a server, right? You use it for some project in which you want files to have a history, with the option of seeing the changes that a file had? (Just to make sure as a failsafe, not implying that you do.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to change the contents of the directory, then you should store it unzipped. Having it in zip file will exhaust storage on server much faster, as if you were storing every version of your zip as a separate file on your server.

---

[Zip format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) has one cool properly: every file inside archive takes some segment of bytes, and is compressed/decompressed independently of all the other files. As the result, if you have a 100 MB zip, and modify two files inside each having size 1 MB, then the new zip will have at most 2 MB of new data, the rest 98 MB will be most likely by byte-exact copies of some pieces of the old zip. So it is in theory possible to represent small in-zip changes as small deltas. But there are many problems in practice.

First of all, you must be sure that you don't recompress the unchanged files. If you make both the first zip and the second zip from scratch using different programs, program versions, compression settings, etc., you can get slightly different compression on the unchanged files. As the result, the actual bytes in zip file will greatly differ, and any hope for small delta will be lost. The better approach is taking the first zip, and adding/removing files in it.

The main problem however is how SVN stores deltas. [As far as I know](https://github.com/apache/subversion/blob/trunk/subversion/libsvn_delta/xdelta.c), SVN uses [xdelta algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta) for computing deltas. This algorithm is perfectly capable of detecting equal blocks inside zip file, if given unlimited memory. The problem is that SVN uses memory-limited version with a window of [size = 100 KB](https://github.com/apache/subversion/blob/trunk/subversion/libsvn_delta/delta.h#L45). Even if you simply remove a segment longer than 100 KB from a file, then SVN's delta computation will break on it, and the rest of the file will be simply copied into delta. Most likely, the delta will take as much space as the whole file takes.